# jQuery "view.js" doesn't work in a page loaded with the jQuery load function

Tags: jquery, photo, viewer

Here is my code :

```
var t_slide = $("#6_toggle");
t_slide.load("6_toggle/1.html");
```

Here is 1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" URL PATH .. js/view.min.js"></script> 

<a class="view" ... </a>    
<a class="view" ... </a>
```

It works well when I open 1.html directly but it doesn't when I load it in my div with the load function

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because the script url isn't valid anymore as `1.html` isn't in the same directory. The script is loaded relatively to the page where it is executed.

Add `../` before your path or make it an absolute one starting with `/` (if you want your page to work in both cases).

Comment: I have tried 2 things :
- I put the js file into 6_toggle and I linkded it in 1.html adding:
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.min.js"></script>
And I have also tried to link it adding : <script type="text/javascript" src="/6_toggle/view.min.js"></script> 
Nothing works

Comment: And isn't your view.js dependant of other resources (jQuery comes to mind...) ? Are you sure you don't have the same problem for those resources ? What's the error in the console ?

Comment: The jquery file is linked to my page :( I'm slowly loosing my hair